# How many rewards do you get from each person / good during ship battles?

Tags: sid-meiers-pirates

In Sid Meier's Pirates during the ship battles you will occasionally see people and goods falling off the ships. If you pick them up what will they give you as "rewards"? I know crew will give you crew and goods will give you goods. The question really is, How many "rewards" do you get from each?

Comment: Your title needs to be a bit more descriptive.

Comment: A person represents one person, and a good represents one good, type determined by the cargo of the ship they came from.

Comment: huh, i always thought that was just purely visual effect.  Never knew you could pick them up.

Comment: @Sconibulus You should make your comment an answer, then using what I added in my answer apply it to yours because it's only fair to.Once you have I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A person represents one person, and a good represents one good, type determined by the cargo of the ship they came from. 
>   --Sconibulus

Treasure chests can be picked up from sunken ships. Each chest is worth 50 gold and each crew member is worth 1 crewman. [**Source**](http://sidmeierspirates.wikia.com/wiki/Naval_Combat#Flotsam_and_Overboard_Crew)

Comment: Which is allowed as an answer, sadly there really isnt anything against it and if you want sources then just say so.

Comment: @Fistosaur Two things, look at the stackoverflow meta for something about rep shy individuals not creating answers. Next, please just ask for a source before berating someone, you may check the source provided.

Comment: @Cole It's allowed, but it's usually considered good etiquette to ask, first.  It's not a requirement by any stretch, and neither is downvoting for any particular reason, as long as you're voting on the content.  And I'd like to remind both of you that our overriding rule is, "Be Nice".

Comment: @fbueckert You are completely right, I didn't ask, just took the initiative. So If he creates the answer, I'll delete mine. Also, Can we make that show up somewhere in the comments section? "Constructive comments and niceness appreciated". [I also didn't know that was actually a rule.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)

Comment: Go ahead and keep it, you went ahead and took the initiative to source it. I was remembering from playing the game several years ago, so didn't feel confident enough to post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The information by Cole is incorrect. While one person equals one person one good doesn't equal one good.

1 good could equal:

1. 100 gold
2. 5 food